# Google Map in Android 2.3.4 shows gray box on both AVD and real device

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I'm trying to show a simple google map on my real Samsung device where Android version is 2.3.4.

- got my SHA1 key
- got my API key from google

Here is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.neighbourhoodlocator"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <!-- External storage for caching. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <!-- My Location -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <!-- Maps API needs OpenGL ES 2.0. -->
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyBq8ATEI-DmBtso1T13S_DGfiT7cBgEav8" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.neighbourhoodlocator.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here is my main.xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"     
        android:layout_width="match_parent"        
        android:layout_height="match_parent"        
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my Mainactivity.java file:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Now the issue I'm having when I launch it on the real device, it doesn't crash, nor it throws any exception (No "Invalid Authorization" either); only thing I can see on the screen is a blank (gray box) with "+" and "-" button. I've tried `Activity` instead of `FragmentActivity`, application crashed.

I checked the logcat trace:

```
10-12 23:14:34.989: W/dalvikvm(15055): VFY: unable to resolve instance field 28
10-12 23:14:35.119: W/dalvikvm(15055): Unable to resolve superclass of Lmaps/p/w; (743)
10-12 23:14:35.119: W/dalvikvm(15055): Link of class 'Lmaps/p/w;' failed
10-12 23:14:35.119: W/dalvikvm(15055): Unable to resolve superclass of Lmaps/ap/as; (6267)
10-12 23:14:35.119: W/dalvikvm(15055): Link of class 'Lmaps/ap/as;' failed
10-12 23:14:35.139: W/dalvikvm(15055): Unable to resolve superclass of Lmaps/af/k; (5294)
10-12 23:14:35.139: W/dalvikvm(15055): Link of class 'Lmaps/af/k;' failed
10-12 23:14:35.139: E/dalvikvm(15055): Could not find class 'maps.af.k', referenced from method maps.ag.an.a
10-12 23:14:35.139: W/dalvikvm(15055): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 5139 (Lmaps/af/k;) in Lmaps/ag/an;
```

I added the `google-play-services_lib` appropriately. and also added the `android-support-v4.jar` is also in "Android private libraries".

Notice that the project build target is:  Google APIs 4.2.2
and the android version in my Samsung phone is: 2.3.4

I've been trying last couple of days, I also tried in the emulator, same thing is happening.
Please help me to solve the issue.
Thanks.

Comment: enabled map for android in google api console?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.. I have solved it. Android emulators aren't working. You should  work your app on your phone. When exporting your project, your sha1 is changing. You must copy that sha1 and make a new API-KEY in google api console. (don't forget the change manifest file). After uploading your phone, it works..

Comment: I'm actually using my phone to run the project. And I already got API-KEY from google api console.
I'm not sure what did u mean by exporting the project...